# table background issue (left, right and middle as images)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the background for the first row of the table using three images (left, right and middle). The middle can be an image or just a color fill.

The code is in this Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bumpy009/c3txj/13/

The result should look like this:

[image]

I am only able to make one arrow appear at a time, not both at once, nor fill the middle area with color.

I need to use the table bg method since I am planning to use this class for different  tables with different widths and different cell widths.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of using table you can achieve this using divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only apply one background image to a table.

If you apply the left and right classes to the respective  tags it will work

http://jsfiddle.net/tXGCa/2/

Comment: its probably a good idea to use gifs for both images too as it looks like the right arrow has a transparency that is going to upset the right cell when the background color sits under it.

Comment: I made the images in photoshop for this question. Please ignore the quality. I don't think the th method will work for me since the cells have fixed width.

Comment: I don't understand why the cells having a fixed width would make a difference. The images will just sit in the top right and left of the cell, then you can apply the background color #c7698b to the other <th>  http://jsfiddle.net/tXGCa/3/

Comment: The width of the first/last cell would at least have to be the width of the bg image. They can't be smaller or the bg image would be cut.

Comment: I guess I will have to create a new background for each table with the exact width. Thanks anyway.

Comment: ok gotcha. http://jsfiddle.net/tXGCa/5/  This way you wrap it in a div with the image sat in the top left corner. You might need another div to extend the heading colour across the top of the table though, if you put a color in the table cells it will overlay the arrows and they will be hidden.

Comment: That's probably as close to a solution as it gets. Thanks.